# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn', tried install package

Tags: python, machine-learning, imblearn

I wish to import some libraries in imblearn(from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler), but this error occured:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn'.

I already tried
pip install imbalanced-learn and conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn

Comment: What was the error message you got when trying to install it using pip?

Answer (score 0):

Activate your conda environment and install the imbalanced-learn module with pip

```
pip install imbalanced-learn
```

Comment: from the question: "I already tried pip install imbalanced-learn"